# Django: update one table based on another

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have two tables `Table1` and `Table2` with the same field `hash_str`.

```py
from django.db import models


class Table1:
    data = JSONField(...)
    hash_str = CharField(...)


class Table2:
    name = CharField(...)
    parsed = DateTimeField(...)
    hash_str = CharField(...)
    is_updated = BooleanField(...)
# ...
```

Sometimes i need to update `Table2` instances based on `Table1` instances with the same hash. But **i want to use `Table2.objects.bulk_update(...)` for it**. Because there is too much instances to update them one by one like this:

```py
# ...
for t2_obj in Table2.objects.filter(is_updated=False):
    t1_obj = Table1.objects.get(hash_str=t2_obj.hash_str)

    t2_obj.name = t1_obj.data["name"]
    t2_obj.parsed = t1_obj.data["parsed"]
    t2_obj.is_updated = True

    t2_obj.save()
# ...
```

**How can i do it properly?**

Comment: What if there is no "match"?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem the code i showed here - just an example. Of course in final code i handle Table1.DoesNotExists exception.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem actually, if there is no "match", i do nothing... just not updating t2_obj

Comment: `Table1.objects.get(hash_str=t2_obj.hash_str)` raises an error if the `hash_str` can not be found.

Answer (score 1):

You can work with a [**`Subquery`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

Table2.objects.filter(is_updated=False).update(
    is_updated=True,
    name=Coalesce(
        Subquery(
            Table1.objects.filter(hash_str=OuterRef('hash_str')).values(
                'data__name'
            )[:1]
        ),
        'name',
    ),
    parsed=Coalesce(
        Subquery(
            Table1.objects.filter(hash_str=OuterRef('hash_str')).values(
                'data__parsed'
            )[:1]
        ),
        'parsed',
    ),
)
```

That being said, I don't think it is good to store the data in two tables, that is *data duplication*, which turns out to eventually cause more trouble. Usually it is better that there is *one turth*: one model that contains the data and thus determines what the `name` is in this case.

Comment: Looks like a solution. I'll check it in my case soon.

Regarding data duplication: the entities from Table1 are not stored permanently - this is a kind of raw state of the entities in Table2. After Table2 entities are completely updated, Table1 is cleared.